# How to write and loop a list on a column in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

How to write and loop the above list on a specific column in python dataframe, so that the outcome will be ...

Dataframe:

Column N (For example)

```
a   
b   
c   
d  
e  
f  
g  
h  
a  
b  
c  
d  
e  
f  
g  
h  
...  
(many times)   
...  
a  
b  
c  
d  
e  
f  
g  
h
```

Or, is there any other way to perform the transformation above without the need of using a `list`? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't name your lists as `list`

Comment: You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat list with `list * n` where n is the number of times it repeats. Then assign it to `'Column N'` of the dataframe, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Column N'] = list * 5
print(df)
```

Comment: It returns "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'", as the column N was inserted with value = np.nan, where np.nan is 'float' but not 'int'. In this case, I would like to ask how to change the values in column N to int? Thanks.

Comment: you have `np.nan` in the dataframe column, use `df['Column N'].fillna(0, inplace=True)` to replace `nan` value with `0`

Answer (score 2):

The `times` variable is how many times you want to repeat. Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

letters = 'abcdefgh'
times = 4
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column Name': [x for x in letters]*times})
print(df)
```

or this:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase

times = 4
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column Name': [x for x in ascii_lowercase[:8]]*times})
print(df)
```

`ascii_lowercase` returns all the letters of the alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

First dont use `list` for variable name, because `builtin` (python code word), and then for repeat use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
import numpy as np

L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
N =  2
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.tile(L, N)})
print (df)
   col
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    f
6    g
7    h
8    a
9    b
10   c
11   d
12   e
13   f
14   g
15   h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.DataFrame(columns=['column name'],data= ['1', np.nan, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']*5))
```